# Alinhar radio buttons a direita de um select

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma linha que está sendo alinhada no centro da seguinte maneira:

```
.row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Dentro dessa linha possui duas colunas, uma com um select e outra com radio buttons que aparece conforme a opção selecionada no select. Preciso que as radio buttons estejam ao lado do select centralizado.

Tentei algo como:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-3">
      <div class="select">
         <select [(ngModel)]="controlaRadios" name="primeiroFiltroName" class="select-text">
         <option hidden selected class="dropdown-item">Primeiro filtro</option>
         <option value="1" class="dropdown-item">Todos</option>
         <option value="2" class="dropdown-item">Tipo de anúncio</option>
         </select>
         <span class="select-highlight"></span>
         <span class="select-bar"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="controlaRadios == 2" class="col-3">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline1" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample">
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">Premium</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample">
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">Clássico</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline3" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample">
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline3">Grátis</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Meu select aparece alinhado, mas assim que aparece as radios, o template é quebrado.

Fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso deixar as radios do lado do select alinhado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ou sei layout está quebrando simplesmente porque não cabem todos os elementos dentro da `col-3`

A minha dica é colocar tudo apenas em um `col` em vez de dividir em duas. Porém em telas muito estreitas vc precisa de fazer um `@media` para ajustar `d-flex` para ficar como `flex-direction: column;` e `align-items: center;`

Veja o código que usei para colocar tudo em uma coluna apenas. `col-12`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.13/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.row, .d-flex{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 566px) {
    .d-flex{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 d-flex">
                    <div class="select">
                        <select [(ngModel)]="controlaRadios" name="primeiroFiltroName" class="select-text">
                        <option hidden selected class="dropdown-item">Primeiro filtro</option>
                        <option value="1" class="dropdown-item">Todos</option>
                        <option value="2" class="dropdown-item">Tipo de anúncio</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="select-highlight"></span>
                        <span class="select-bar"></span>
                    </div>
                
                    <div *ngIf="controlaRadios == 2" class="ml-3">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline1" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">Premium</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">Clássico</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline3" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline3">Grátis</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aumentei a col mas ainda centraliza os dois aqui, em vez de aparecer ao lado do select. eu uso o material design bootstrap

Comment: usar as colunas foi a forma que pensei para os radio ficarem ao lado do select... usando em uma row, não consegui pensar em outra forma

Comment: @RenaotPLS eu achei que vc estava usando Bootstrap, até reverti a edição que tinha feito incluindo as tags, me desculpe! Vou ver se ajusto colocando as classes corretas do framework

Comment: ok obrigado!!!!

Comment: @RenaotPLS acabei de editar, agora com o CDN do MD Bootstrap e deixei do jeito que eu acho mais correto...

Comment: olhei, mas o select não está centralizado. ele deve ser centralizado e ao lado dele os radio buttons :/

Comment: dessa forma a centralização é realizada tanto no select quanto nos radios

Comment: @RenaotPLS Da forma que vc quer só colocando turo em uma `col` só... Vou editar novamente a resposta pera ai

Comment: @RenaotPLS agora sim resposta editada

Comment: se eu definir a coluna como 12, o input vai ocupar praticamente toda minha tela, visualmente fica feio. acho que provavelmente não tem uma forma simples de fazer isso, né?

Comment: @RenaotPLS tem sim, é só vc colocar um largura máxima pro seu input, tipo `max-width:300px` por exemplo, e vc ainda pode usar a regra `Media` para mudar esse width em telas menores que 566px. Ou quando vc mostrar os radios vc tb muda a largura do inputo, ai seria com JS, vc vai ter que avaliar

Comment: consegui um resultado parecido com o que eu precisava